# How to upload shopping cart data to a cookie?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cookies, mongoose

I have a problem with my project that is an eCommerce website, and is when the user signs in to the page an makes his order it´s added to the shopping cart, but when another user sings in he can see the order of the other user.

The order it´s added to the collection orders and that collection it´s store together with the collection of products and credentials (same database)

I know that I have to add the information to a cookie session so only that user can see his cart, after browsing for a while the npm connect-mongodb-session, but and tried to add information directly o a cookie with req.cookie, and I am fairly new to cookies.

Below you can see the database schema the get.post of the page and that it´s added to the collection with new Order.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);

var app = express();

var store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: "mongodb+srv://<user><password>@cluster0- 
   okw4h.mongodb.net/productosDB",
  collection: "orders"
});

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(cookieParser());

store.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});

app.use(session({
    secret: "Our little secret.",
    cookie: { expires : new Date(Date.now() + 360000) },
    store: store,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://<user><password>@cluster0- 
   okw4h.mongodb.net/productosDB",
   {useNewUrlParser: true});

const orderSchema = {
    amount: Number,
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    total: Number
};

app.post("/cambio", function(req, res) {
   var inputValue = req.body.vote;

    if (inputValue == "add") {
    var cantidad = req.body.option;
    var name = productName.name;
    var price = productName.price;

    totalPrice = cantidad * price;

     const order = new Order ({
       amount: cantidad,
       name: name,
       price: price,
       total: totalPrice
    });

    res.redirect("/cambio");
   }
});
```

Comment: how are you differentiating the order for users, add user id in order collection and find all orders based on user id, show the orders for that user only.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of res.cookie("Cookie_name", value) in order to make cookies for users and then request them using req.cookies for getting the user's data. The code below will help you with making cookies.

```
//JSON object to be added to cookie 
let users = { 
name : "Ritik", 
Age : "18"
} 
  
//Route for adding cookie 
app.get('/setuser', (req, res)=>{ 
res.cookie("userData", users); 
res.send('user data added to cookie'); 
}); 
  
//Iterate users data from cookie 
app.get('/getuser', (req, res)=>{ 
//shows all the cookies 
res.send(req.cookies); 
});
```